# Subsections without numbering in ToC and document

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, numbering, memoir

I have a table of contents which I want to modify.  I want subsections without a number, in the document and the ToC.

I'm using `memoir`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, makeidx]{memoir}
```

I have the following table of ToC style

```
\settocdepth{subsection}
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
\maxsecnumdepth{subsection}
\settocdepth{subsection}
\maxtocdepth{subsection}
```

This results in  (ToC)

```
1 Chapter Titel......................
    1.1  Section......................  
        1.1.1  Subsection......................
```

I want  this

```
1 Chapter Titel......................
    1.1  Section ...................... 
         Subsection ......................
```

Any help would be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\settocdepth{subsection}
% \setsecnumdepth{section}% default

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{foo}

\section{foobar}

\subsection{foobargnu}

\end{document}​
```

[image]

Comment: I'd just use `\settocdepth{subsection}`, never quite figured out what  `\maxtocdepth` is used for

Comment: @daleif Indeed .... the manual, though, states that `\settocdepth` *"can only be used after the preamble"*, which seems to be incorrect.

Comment: I don’t have a clue! After reading your and  @daleif his commend I deleted  
{\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
\maxsecnumdepth{subsection}
\settocdepth{subsection}
\maxtocdepth{subsection}
}
So the solution of lockstep works perfect! 
A time ago I copied the code from an example during a Latex crash course!

Comment: @lockstep: Interesting, I've noted it in my TODO list for `memoir`. `\maxsecnumdepth` is used by `\mainmatter` but as far as I can see `\maxtocdepth` is not used anywhere. `\settocdepth` actually write the depth to the `toc` file, where as `\maxtocdepth` does not.